# Why does my database structure and SELECT operations generate NULLs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, trigger, import, csv

*I'm not too experienced with database problems, so please excuse the wall of text, I believe the context is important to understand the problem and goal.*

---

I receive a CSV file from another system every day that I want to retain in a database running on Microsoft SQL Server. To accomplish this, I have a PowerShell-script scheduled daily that uses the bcp utility to "load" the CSV (*accounts.csv*) into a table (`accounts_stage`) that has the "exact" layout of the CSV file. In addition, I "write" the *timestamp* into another table (`import_stage`). The `accounts_stage` table has a trigger set, and bcp is configured to fire that trigger.

After the import is finished, I want to "normalize" the data. For a basic example, assume this concerns only the *contract number* (in the CSV file a field called "Vnr"), which is a string. I have another table (`contracts`), which gets filled by the trigger:

```
INSERT INTO dzp.contractid(vnr)
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.Vnr
FROM dzp.accounts_stage a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT id.vnr
    FROM dzp.contractid id
)
```

This should, and seems to accomplish, add all *contract numbers* that are ever imported to the table `contractids`. `contractids.contractId` is a BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, IDENTITY, and auto increment.

I add the *import-metadata* to my table like this:

```
   CREATE TABLE #IMPORTMETADATA
            ([importid] bigint
            ,[generated_timestamp] datetime
            ,[imported_timestamp] datetime
            )
    INSERT INTO #IMPORTMETADATA
        SELECT TOP 1 [importid], [timestamp_import], [generated_timestamp]         
    FROM
            [QGTAA].[dzp].[import]
        ORDER BY
            [timestamp_import] DESC
```

Next, the trigger should INSERT the data FROM `accounts_stage` INTO `accounts`, such that the `contractId` is replaced (from the original string representation to the PRIMARY KEY of the `contracts` table).

```
INSERT INTO [dzp].[accounts]
      ([Udnr]
      ,[ContractId]
      -- snip
      ,[generated_timestamp]
      ,[importid]
      )
SELECT 
    a.[Udnr], 
    cid.contractId, 
    -- snip
    meta.[generated_timestamp], 
    meta.[importid]
FROM [QGTAA].[dzp].[accounts_stage] a
LEFT JOIN dzp.contractid cid ON cid.vnr = a.Vnr
CROSS JOIN #IMPORTMETADATA meta
```

However, this last step fails, because the SELECT operation in the last block yields rows where `contractId` IS NULL, which I did not expect. Now I believe the issue is somewhere with the LEFT JOIN, but I'm not sure why.

**Questions**

1. Can someone please point me in the right direction on this specific problem?
2. I am not too experienced with databases, is this even a sane way of accomplishing what I intend, or is this a completely insane approach? Is there a better way?

Thank you!

Comment: For a better understanding of joins, start here: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a problem with your first `NOT EXISTS`. Let's take a look at your current query:

```
INSERT INTO dzp.contractid(vnr)
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.Vnr
FROM dzp.accounts_stage a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT id.vnr
    FROM dzp.contractid id
)
```

So, what's happening here is that the `NOT EXISTS` that you are using will return true **only** when the `dzp.contractid` table is empty. Once it has one row (or more), the `NOT EXISTS` will return `false` for every row of your main table, since `SELECT id.vnr FROM dzp.contractid` has a result set, and you end up inserting duplicated values in your table.

What you need to do is correlate this subquery with the main table:

```
INSERT INTO dzp.contractid(vnr)
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.Vnr
FROM dzp.accounts_stage a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT id.vnr
    FROM dzp.contractid id
    WHERE id.vnr = a.vnr
);
```

Also, the `CROSS JOIN` with the data from the latest import doesn't make much sense to me, and neither the fact that you aren't checking if the data exists already in the `accounts` table.

Comment: Additionally, the final step requires contractId to not be null but the query is left joining the table that it comes from and leaving open the possibility it will be null.  If it's required that it exists then this should be changed to an inner join.

Comment: @indiri yeah, the last query needs to be rewritten, but I don't understand completely if that's what op needs or not

Comment: I finally came to continue working on this problem, and what you describe is exactly right. The solution works, i had to add the part about the import though. The import table only stores the one file that is currently being imported (as I need to get metadata about the source file into the database through Powershell + bcp. Thanks!